# Move div up by 50% of its own height

Tags: css, flexbox

**TL;DR:** can you move a div up by 50% of its own height and still have the rest of the document flow right below it?

---

I have to make a layout where there is a series of images (fixed width:height ratio) with captions (variable length of text).

**I'm pretty sure I have to use flex or grid**. Here are the constraints that point towards a `display: flex` container with `display: flex||grid` children:

1. Fixed number of items per line even though screen width might vary
2. The boxes containing the caption texts of the same line should all be of the same height, even though the text is of variable length.
3. If a line isn't filled with images, the fewer images should just be centered (i.e. parent can't be `grid`).

**Here's the kicker**:

4. **The captions should be vertically centered around the bottom of their respective images.** (Exactly like in the snippet below, when `transform` is enabled.)

**Why `translateY` can't work**: this would be easy to do with a `translateY(-50%)` (see snippet below) but then I don't have any control over the vertical spacing between two lines of images. If, because of the variable caption length, the caption boxes on a row are 100px tall, I'll have a 50px margin below that row, if the next row has caption boxes only 80px tall, the margin below that one will be 40px... I'm trying to get a consistent margin below each row.

**The snippet**: layout is correct. When `translateY` is *enabled*, captions are properly positioned in relation to their respective images. When `translateY` is *disabled*, vertical spacing between rows of images can be determined. I wish to do both.

```css
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}
section {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: calc(100% / 3);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.img {
    background: center / cover no-repeat url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/02/16/20/29/new-york-4854718_1280.jpg)
}
.img::before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 65%;
}
.text {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px red;
    flex: 1;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<section>
    <div class="img"></div>
    <div class="text"><span>Convallis cursus ornare mus luctus varius fusce tempus arcu quisque</span></div>
</section>
<section>
    <div class="img"></div>
    <div class="text"><span>Eleifend lorem facilisis dictumst phasellus aenean conubia libero.</span></div>
</section>
<section>
    <div class="img"></div>
    <div class="text"><span>Nam ut gravida nisi scelerisque</span></div>
</section>
<section>
    <div class="img"></div>
    <div class="text"><span>Ligula quisque nibh class sociosqu netus laoreet interdum volutpat mus</span></div>
</section>
<section>
    <div class="img"></div>
    <div class="text"><span>Duis nec maecenas ultricies ridiculus nascetur nisi rutrum dignissim nam</span></div>
</section>
```

Comment: Probably better off moving the text box up a fixed number instead of a 50% of its height. This way at least it is consistent across all boxes. Plus if the text is too long you will cover up more image as well. This can be achieved with js if you really need to. If you can use js, please tag the question with the javascript tag

Comment: @Huangism Yeah that's why I didn't add the javascript tag. And my question is very specifically about the 50% of its own height. This is the design I have to make.

Comment: *why the specs don't allow it.* --> because you know the height AFTER placing the element inside the flow so you cannot go back to change the flow using that value of height because it may affect the height again and we will have an infinite loop BUT maybe there is a hack I am not aware of.

Comment: are all images of same height?

Answer (score 0):

As I commented, I am pretty sure this is not possible using any common property or classic layout BUT we can *hack* it.

Here is an idea of hack where I will rely on duplicating the text. The in flow text will have a height X and another out of the flow text will have a height X*2. The in flow text will define our visual distance with the second row and will be invisible while the other one will be visible and ... check the below snippet and you will understand everything:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

section {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.img {
  background: center / cover no-repeat url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/02/16/20/29/new-york-4854718_1280.jpg)
}

.img::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 65%;
}

.text {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
  flex: 1;
  position: relative; /* here and not inside span !!*/
}


/* The hack start here */

.text span {
  display: block;
  line-height: 0; /* reset line-height here to control it with pseudo element*/
}

.text span::before,
.text span::after {
  content: attr(data-text);
  display: block;
}

.text span::before {
  opacity: 0; /* in flow text invisible*/
  line-height: 0.65; /* will define the height X */
}

.text span::after {
  position: absolute; /* Out of the flow*/
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 200%; /* Make it 2*X, where X is the height of .text defined by the content of before*/
  /* put back a normal line-height
     should be twice the one of the before but it can be slightly different to avoid some overflow */
  line-height: 1.2; 
  transform: translateY(-50%); /* Now you can translate it !*/
  /*Move the style here*/
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px red;
  /**/
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="img"></div>
  <div class="text"><span data-text="Convallis cursus ornare mus luctus varius fusce tempus arcu quisque"></span></div>
</section>
<section>
  <div class="img"></div>
  <div class="text"><span data-text="Eleifend lorem facilisis dictumst phasellus aenean conubia libero."></span></div>
</section>
<section>
  <div class="img"></div>
  <div class="text"><span data-text="Nam ut gravida nisi scelerisque"></span></div>
</section>
<section>
  <div class="img"></div>
  <div class="text"><span data-text="Ligula quisque nibh class sociosqu netus laoreet interdum volutpat mus"></span></div>
</section>
<section>
  <div class="img"></div>
  <div class="text"><span data-text="Duis nec maecenas ultricies ridiculus nascetur nisi rutrum dignissim nam"></span></div>
</section>
```

Comment: That was close! I've only managed to get close myself and I'm asking here in hopes that there's some combination of hacks I didn't think of.

Comment: @Sheraff I will probably find another hack ;) but at least you have an idea how we can approximate the result

Comment: Absolutely, I'm already trying to see how I can make this work with more than just text in the caption box.

Comment: wouldn't the `line-height: .65` cause drift over a few lines?

Comment: @Sheraff it's applied the invisible text. The line-height is all the trick here. If you make it almost half the line-height of the visible text you will make the height almost the half and we have our hack.

Comment: Yes but why `0.65` and not `0.6` for being half of `line-height: 1.2` ?

Comment: @Sheraff theorically it should be half 1.2 but if you try you may face some overflow of the text at the bottom so we can make it slightly bigger (or change the 1.2) to keep a good result. Line-height is tricky and we may face rounding issue so the reality is a bit different from the theory BUT the trick rely on a relation of 2x

Comment: @Sheraff worth to note that the 0.65 is defining the height and then I am using height:200% to have twice that heigth so it's not line-height:1.2 that is defining the height of the ::after element that's why we can change line-height without affecting the hack. The line-height on after should be around twice the one of the ::before to match the height:200% (yes I know it's not easy ...)

Comment: @Sheraff don't forget to also accept the answer if you are no more looking for new ones

Answer (score -2):

Is it possible to use JavaScript in project?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
</head>

<body>

  <style>
    body {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      justify-content: center;
    }
    
    section {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      width: calc(100% / 3);
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }
    
    .img {
      background: center / cover no-repeat url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/02/16/20/29/new-york-4854718_1280.jpg)
    }
    
    .img::before {
      content: '';
      display: block;
      padding-bottom: 65%;
    }
    
    .text div {
      background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
      box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px red;
      flex: 1;
    }
  </style>

  <section>
    <div class="img"></div>
    <div class="text">
      <div>Convallis cursus ornare mus luctus varius fusce tempus arcu quisque. Convallis cursus ornare mus luctus varius fusce tempus arcu quisque.</div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <div class="img"></div>
    <div class="text">
      <div>Eleifend lorem facilisis dictumst phasellus aenean conubia libero.</div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <div class="img"></div>
    <div class="text">
      <div>Nam ut gravida nisi scelerisque</div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <div class="img"></div>
    <div class="text">
      <div>Ligula quisque nibh class sociosqu netus laoreet interdum volutpat mus</div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <div class="img"></div>
    <div class="text">
      <div>Duis nec maecenas ultricies ridiculus nascetur nisi rutrum dignissim nam</div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <script>
    const text = document.querySelectorAll('.text div');
    const textLen = text.length;

    for (let i = 0; i < textLen; i += 1) {
      text[i].style.marginTop = '-' + (text[i].scrollHeight / 2) + 'px';
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: My script was tested and worked for me in this case in editor, but feel free to modify it anyway you want as it is trivial solution as you stated. Transform and Absolute positioning wouldn’t match both of criterias, so there’s need to use another method of repositioning element. As it needs to be dynamic, short script could be the possibility that doesn’t affect the performance.

Comment: It actually doesn't work. I just properly tested. When assigning a negative `margin-bottom` or `margin-top` to *every* `section` or every `.text`, it ends up that the `flex: 1` is ignored and the caption boxes of a row aren't all of the same size anymore.