# Move dynamic height box up 50% of its own height without breaking flow

Tags: html, css

I want the following layout in css but the red box should be of dynamic height between 10 and 150px. The top of the blue box should be behind the middle of the red box.

[image]

For a fixed height, this is very simple to achieve with negative margin like this:

```css
.wrapper {
  margin-top:100px;
  background-color:blue;
  padding:20px;
  padding-top:0;
  max-width:250px;
  
  border:solid 1px yellow;
}

.subbox{
  height:30px;
  background-color:green;
  margin-top:30px;
}

#logo {
  height:150px;
  background-color:red;
  
  margin-top:-75px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="logo">
  
  </div>
  <div class="subbox">
  
  </div>
  
  <div class="subbox">
  
  </div>

</div>
```

However, as the height of the box is dynamic, I can't tell what value negative margin should be.

I also considered using`transformY` like this:

```
#logo {
  height:150px;

  background-color:red;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

But then the top card is taken out of the flow, leading to a large gap for the green bars. [image]

Is it possible to move the red box up by 50% while maintaining the distance to the green bars without javascript?

Note: There is a question with almost the same title [Move div up by 50% of its own height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60328786/move-div-up-by-50-of-its-own-height) but it is for a very specific and different scenario

Comment: _"Is it possible to move the red box up by 50% while maintaining the distance to the green bars without javascript?"_ - not really, I don't think ... margin or padding given in percentage always refer to the _width_ of the containing block, even for `-top`/`-bottom`. And a translate transform or relative positioning, leave the _original_ space the element would have in normal flow, reserved.

Comment: Now if you _really_ needed just a "blue box", you could emulate the top portion of it with a pseudo element absolutely positioned behind the red one - `top: 50; bottom: 0; height: auto` ... but I am guessing in reality the layout you need to achieve is probably not _that_ simple? A need for borders / background image/gradient, would complicate things (or make this workaround completely unfeasible to begin with.)

Comment: @CBroe nice idea. But yes, in reality the box has also rounded corners and a shadow to it. But still, a good workaround.

Comment: Have subboxes fixed height? If so, then blue box can be a pseudo of logo

Comment: @Eugene the green boxes have a fixed height actually. But the blue box depends on the size of the red box, so the height of blue box is also dynamic.

Comment: So, it can be like: `#logo::before { inset: 50% -20px -140px -20px }`. I can try to make an answer with demo, if you want

Answer (score 0):

I had to add an extra wrapper, hope this is not a problem

```css
.wrapper {
  padding: 0 20px 20px;
  max-width: 250px;
}

.logo-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 120px;
}

.logo-wrapper::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  inset: 50% -20px calc(0px - 2 * 30px - 2 * 30px - 20px) -20px;
  background-color: blue;
  z-index: -1;
}

.subbox {
  height: 30px;
  background-color: green;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

#logo {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="logo-wrapper">
    <div id="logo"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="subbox"></div>
  
  <div class="subbox"></div>
</div>
```